# Fastest sorting algorithm for a specific situation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting, performance

What is the fastest sorting algorithm for a large number (tens of thousands) of groups of 9 positive double precision values, where each group must be sorted individually? So it's got to sort fast a small number of possibly repeated double precision values, many times in a row.
The values are in the [0..1] interval. I don't care about space complexity or stability, just about speed.

Comment: so you sort each group of 9 values and then merge all groups of 9 values together or do you just need to sort each group of 9 values and then just let them be?

Comment: @Justin just let them be

Comment: @luvieere ok, then sorting networks are indeed the way to go.

Comment: On what hardware? SIMD and possibly GPU availability can effect algorithm choice.

Comment: @Pete GPU indeed, pixel shader 2.0, data to be sorted consists of a 3 x 3 vicinity of each pixel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorting each group individually, merge sort would probably be easiest to implement with good results.

A sorting network would probably be the fastest solution:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network

Comment: The benefit of a sorting network is you can add in some very fast optimisations if you know about the characteristics of the data, IE if you know that element 3 is ALWAYS smaller than element 8 you have saved yourself a lot of processing time.

Comment: Just to add a quick comment as well, I had a tast to sort 7 integers in the fastest time possible, this sort would be performed billions of times and by far (and I mean by far) the fastest was a sorting network.

Comment: Don't forget the link to compute the sorting network: http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html. Indicates 27 comparisons needed for 9 values.

Comment: @Justin thanks for the link, that's a handy program!

Sorting networks also have the benefit you have no loops in the code which usually will save you some overhead as well.

Comment: I wanted to remind that depends on how the data is given to the algorithm. For i.e. if the data is already sorted a bubble sort will be faster and a quicksort. If the data is not sorted a quicksort will be cleary faster than a bubble sort. So, knowing about the input should help about the desicion.

Comment: @johncatfish: random comment ?

Comment: What range were the 7 integers in Tom? It's plausible that a counting sort would have been faster.

Comment: A sorting network is a nice theoretical construct, and if you were doing sorting in hardware you could build one, but how can it be faster than a corresponding algorithm, given that the size of the table is fixed and you can unroll loops?

Answer (score 1):

Good question because this comes down to "Fastest way to sort an array of 9 elements", and most comparisons between and analysis of sorting methods are about large N. I assume the 'groups' are clearly defined and don't play a real role here.

You will probably have to benchmark a few candidates because a lot of factors (locality) come into play here.

In any case, making it parallel sounds like a good idea. Use `Parallel.For()` if you can use ,NET4.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to try out a few examples to see what works best, as you have an unusual set of conditions.   My guess that the best will be one of

- sorting network
- insertion sort
- quick sort (one level -- insertion sort below)
- merge sort

Given that double precision number are relatively long I suspect you will not do better with a radix sort, but feel free to add it in.

For what its worth, Java uses quick sort on doubles until the number of items to be sorted drops below 7, at which is uses insertion sort. The third option mimics that solution.

Also your overall problem is [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) so you want to make use of parallelism when possible.  The problem looks too small for a distributed solution (more time would be lost in networking than saved), but if set up right, your problem can make use of multiple cores very effectively.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the most cycle-stingy way to sort 9 values. Since the number of values is limited, I would (as Kathy suggested) first do an unrolled insertion sort on the first 4 elements and the second 5 elements. Then I would merge those two groups.

Here's an unrolled insertion sort of 4 elements:

```
if (u[1] < u[0]) swap(u[0], u[1]);
if (u[2] < u[0]) swap(u[0], u[2]);
if (u[3] < u[0]) swap(u[0], u[3]);

if (u[2] < u[1]) swap(u[1], u[2]);
if (u[3] < u[1]) swap(u[1], u[3]);

if (u[3] < u[2]) swap(u[2], u[3]);
```

Here's a merge loop. The first set of 4 elements is in `u`, and the second set of 5 elements in in `v`. The result is in `r`.

```
i = j = k = 0;
while(i < 4 && j < 5){
  if (u[i] < v[j]) r[k++] = u[i++];
  else if (v[j] < u[i]) r[k++] = v[j++];
  else {
    r[k++] = u[i++];
    r[k++] = v[j++];
  }
}
while (i < 4) r[k++] = u[i++];
while (j < 5) r[k++] = v[j++];
```